# How to get id of specific Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing a website which is like bulletin board with stickers on it. So each sticker has a close button. But I cannot find the id of the sticker, which the user clicked on the close button.

```
stickerId = 1;
function createSticker(jsonNewSticker){     // receives json

    str = "<b>Email:</b> "+ jsonNewSticker.email+ 
    "</br> <b>Title:</b> "+ jsonNewSticker.title+
    "</br> <b>Summary:</b> "+ jsonNewSticker.summary+
    "</br> <b>Description:</b> "+ jsonNewSticker.description +
    "</br> <b>Entry expires: </b>" + jsonNewSticker.expiration_date;

    $("#mainForSticks").prepend("<div id= seq-"+ stickerId +" ></div>");
    $("#seq-"+ stickerId).attr("class","sticker");      
    $("#seq-"+ stickerId).html(str);

    $("#seq-"+ stickerId).append("<div id=report><a class=link href=javascript:reportCounter()>Report</a></div>"); // report  
    $("#report").attr("class","reportText");

    $("#seq-"+ stickerId).append("<div id=deleteSticker><a class=link href=javascript:deleteSticker()><b>X</b></a></div>"); // delete 
    $("#deleteSticker").attr("class","delSticker");
    //currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    stickerId++;

}
```

so here each sticker has an id: seq-1 seq-2 seq-3 ...

```
function deleteSticker(){
    // how can I get id of specific sticker
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways.

1st way is passing parameter to it like:

```
$("#seq-"+ stickerId).append("<div id=deleteSticker><a class=link href=javascript:deleteSticker(" + stickerId +")><b>X</b></a></div>"); // delete 

function deleteSticker(ID){
    var x = $("#" + ID);
}
```

2nd way is [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like:

```
$(function(){
    $('div[id^="#seq-"]').click(function(){
       // here is your click.
    });
});
```

Comment: inline javascript fail.  Although the op is using it.  Also if he has multiple stickers the 2nd way will fail

Comment: "inline javascript fail"? Large slabs of hard-coded markup, use of "javascript" pseudo–protocol, links as buttons, XML markup in an HTML document, etc. so why single out the inline listener? The suggested solution is the simplest to implement given the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The sticker is relative to the close button so you don't really need the ID. I just use the `closest()` method and the appropriate selector.

However, whether you need ID or not,  I put a dynamic handler on the sticker close buttons here.  You can add as many stickers as you want.  This makes your inline javascript call to `javascript:anything` obsolete, making the code easier to maintain.

The handler here is using deleteSticker as its callback but you can do whatever you want in it including get the ID (which I show in the alert) or delete the sticker, etc.

Bonus points for stickers with colors? :D

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/W9cEp/)

```
var deleteSticker = function(){
    var sticker = $(this).closest('[id^="seq"]');
        alert("your sticker # is: "+sticker.attr('id'));
    sticker.remove();
}

$('#mainForSticks').on('click', 'a', deleteSticker);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Id in `deleteSticker` function and use it like this

```
function deleteSticker(item){
 var element=document.getElementById(item)
}
```

and add this function like this

```
var elementId="seq-"+ stickerId;
$("#seq-"+ stickerId).append("<div id=deleteSticker><a class=link href=javascript:deleteSticker(elementId)><b>X</b></a></div>"); // delete
```

Comment: Why are you setting `#deleteSticker` class attribute to `delSticker(elementId)`?

Comment: ohh @Musa thanks a lot, I just made a mistake. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("#seq-"+ stickerId).attr("class","sticker");      
$("#seq-"+ stickerId).html(str);

$("#seq-"+ stickerId).append("<div id=report><a class=link href=javascript:reportCounter()>Report</a></div>"); // report  
$("#report").attr("class","reportText");

$("#seq-"+ stickerId).append("<div id=deleteSticker><a class=link href=javascript:deleteSticker()><b>X</b></a></div>"); // delete 
$("#deleteSticker").attr("class","delSticker");
```

To this:

```
$("#seq-"+ stickerId)
    .attr("class","sticker")
    .html(str)
    .append("<div id='report' class='reportText'><a class=link href='#'>Report</a></div>") // report  
    .append("<div id='deleteSticker' class='delSticker'><a class=link href='#'><b>X</b></a></div>"); // delete
```

Add this code outside of the function, in jQuery `$(document).ready({`, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready({
    $('body').on('click', '.delSticker', function() {
        deleteSticker(this);
    });
});
```

Then, change your `deleteSticker()` to:

```
function deleteSticker(elem) {
    $(elem).parents('.sticker').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place for [data attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#custom-data-attribute). They allow unobtrusive JavaScript and don't have any reliance on the document structure (e.g. as does the looking for the closest matching element).

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EN5Ht/2/

I suggest adding the ID of the associated item when the delete button is being generated.

As a side note, it appears that you may be assigning duplicate IDs ("report" and "deleteSticker") if you call `createSticker()` more than once. IDs must be unique.

**Sample HTML**

```
<button data-role="delete-button" data-id="seq-1">Delete</button>
<button data-role="delete-button" data-id="seq-2">Delete</button>
<button data-role="delete-button" data-id="seq-3">Delete</button>

<div id="seq-1">Item 1</div>
<div id="seq-2">Item 2</div>
<div id="seq-3">Item 3</div>
```

Note that there is no inline JavaScript and that we added a `data-role` and a `data-id` to each element. The delete buttons can be any element you want; they can be located anywhere within the document.

**JavaScript**

```
$("body").on("click", "[data-role='delete-button']", function(){
    var button = $(this);
    $("#" + button.data("id")).remove();
});
```

We then listen for all click events on matching elements (now, or dynamically added later) which are designated as delete buttons.

When the event is fired, we retrieve the button responsible and get the value of its `data-id` attribute. This tells us the associated element, which can then be hidden/removed as desired.